# Is there a way to process an Intent in Android without creating an Activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an app that receives a link and sends it to an external server, so the links it's processed there. I followed these steps from [Android Fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive), and I'm also able to send the link to the server.
The problem with this solution is that it creates an empty activity everytime i share a link with my app, and I don't need to display anything(maybe a Toast, but not an activity). I tried calling the method finish() after the link is sent, but I usually get the "Application not responding" message, so I don't think thats the best solution.

Comment: I remember an android podcast where the android team had a discussion with the creator of LinkBubble and he said that he used a transparent activity to intercept the links that the user taps. Here is the code of that app, maybe you can find something interesting or maybe some details on how it worked: https://github.com/brave/link-bubble